# Query Firebase Real-Time Database Swift

Tags: ios, json, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

How one can fetch the details of all the users but the current user from a real-time database on Firebase?

I've been trying to create some queries for my database but without success. This is the first time when dealing with queries in Firebase and find them a bit confusing.

My database structure looks like this:

```
-> users

    ->profile
        ->uid1
            ->email : "some@email.com"
            ->name : "some_name"
            ->favourite
               ->id1
                   ->title : "some_title"
                   ->date : "some_date"
                   ->id : "id1"
               ->id2
                   ->title : "some_title"
                   ->date : "some_date"
                   ->id : "id2"
        ->uid2
            ->email : "some@email.com"
            ->name : "some_name"
            ->favourite
               ->id1
                   ->title : "some_title"
                   ->date : "some_date"
                   ->id : "id1"
               ->id2
                   ->title : "some_title"
                   ->date : "some_date"
                   ->id : "id2"
        ->uid3
            ->email : "some@email.com"
            ->name : "some_name"
            ->favourite
               ->id1
                   ->title : "some_title"
                   ->date : "some_date"
                   ->id : "id1"
               ->id2
                   ->title : "some_title"
                   ->date : "some_date"
                   ->id : "id2"
```

This is what I tried:

```
 Database.database().reference().child("users/profile")
      .queryOrdered(byChild:  "username")
      .queryStarting(atValue: searchBar.text!)
      .queryEnding(atValue: searchBar.text! + "\u{f8ff}")
      .observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
```

Let's suppose the user I am logged in has the user id "uid1", how can I fetch the details of all the other users but the ones of my current user?

Comment: Show how you have tried to solve this. Show your code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> how can I fetch the details of all the other users but the ones of my current user?

There is no specific API to retrieve "all child nodes except this one". This means you have a few options:

1. Retrieve all child nodes, and exclude the user's own node client-side. This is by far the most common approach, since the overhead of the one extra node you read become negligible as the total number of (user) nodes grows.
2. Retrieve two ranges of child nodes: the ones before the current user, and the ones after. This requires that you know the ID of the node before, and after your current user. If you do, you can do a `ref.orderByKey().endAt(idOfUserBefore)` and `ref.orderByKey().start(idOfUserAfter)`.
3. Retrieve all other child nodes as individual calls. This requires that you know the ID of every child node. But if you do know that, it's not as expensive as you may think since [Firebase pipelines the calls over a single connection](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35931526/speed-up-fetching-posts-for-my-social-network-app-by-using-query-instead-of-obse/35932786#35932786).